# Bash not running script at /opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/

Tags: macos, bash

I wanted to have bash autocompletion for git commands, so I dropped a bash script file into `/opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

When I open a new Terminal, the script file in `/opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/` does not get executed. I have verified that the script file is working by running:

```
source /opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
```

Are there any steps missing here to ask OS X to automatically execute scripts in `/opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/`?

Answer (score 8):

In order to automatically load all scripts from a directory, put this in your `~/.bashrc` file

```
# LOAD ALL AUTOCOMPLETIONS IF ANY ARE INSTALLED
if [ -d /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d ]; then
    for F in "/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/"*; do
        if [ -f "${F}" ]; then
            source "${F}";
        fi
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to load them into your shell.

This is done by editing `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` and adding the command `. filename` for each file. This loads the file and makes the functions available. i.e. put your source command in one of these files.

Note that you should not be adding to `/opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/` as only macports should write there. Put the files in your home directory e.g. `~/.bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash`